# How to update product quantity sqlite database Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

CheckOrderExists 2 value add 1.recipe_id 2.qty + button increase qty not update.Addcart if condition not working else condition working.I want to update the qty of product when adding a product.update qty sqlite not show

```
    public void Addcart(String category_name, long recipe_id, String recipe_title, String recipe_time, String recipe_image, String recipe_description, String video_url, String video_id, String content_type, String featured, String tags, long total_views, String _stringVal) {


    try {
        if (!CheckOrderExists(recipe_id).equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
            UpdateOrderData(recipe_id, _stringVal);


            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(KEY_CAT_NAME, category_name);
            values.put(KEY_RECIPE_ID, recipe_id);
            values.put(KEY_RECIPE_TITLE, recipe_title);
            values.put(KEY_RECIPE_TIME, recipe_time);
            values.put(KEY_RECIPE_IMAGE, recipe_image);
            values.put(KEY_RECIPE_DESCRIPTION, recipe_description);
            values.put(KEY_VIDEO_URL, video_url);
            values.put(KEY_VIDEO_ID, video_id);
            values.put(KEY_CONTENT_TYPE, content_type);
            values.put(KEY_FEATURED, featured);
            values.put(KEY_TAGS, tags);
            values.put(KEY_TOTAL_VIEWS, total_views);
            values.put(KEY_QTY, _stringVal);
            // Inserting Row
            db.insert(TABLE_ADDCART, null, values);
            db.close(); // Closing database connection
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {


    }

}
```

CheckOrderExists ZERO IS DELECTE table

```
     public String CheckOrderExists( long recipe_id) {

    String _stringVal = "0";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ADDCART + " WHERE " + KEY_RECIPE_ID+ " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(recipe_id)});
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        _stringVal = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_QTY));


        if (_stringVal.equals("0")) {
            db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_ADDCART + " WHERE " + KEY_RECIPE_ID+" = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(recipe_id)});

        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return _stringVal;
}
```

UPDATEORDER

```
        public void UpdateOrderData(long recipe_id,String _stringVal) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    if (_stringVal.equals("0")) {
        DeleteOrderData(recipe_id);
    } else {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_QTY, _stringVal);
        db.update(TABLE_ADDCART, values, recipe_id + " = ?" , new String[]{String.valueOf(recipe_id)});


    }
    db.close();
}
```

I want when user click "add to cart" button then the quantity will be updated. But quantity is updated after I click the button twice.

Comment: @dda  not qty update bro how to fix bro

Comment: It's hard to say what's going wrong with your snippet. You'd better check the button click callback and make sure the increment triggered at the right position of your code.

Comment: @Horsing    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method OnBtnClick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton with id 'btnaddqty' click button error show

Comment: It's might be help if you minimize your project and figure out where does the callback has been defined correctly and make sure you are increasing your counter as expected. You can make it available in github after desensitize. And we can dig into your code and that maybe helpful.

Comment: @Horsing increasing counter crash app   bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add more logging after every step, similar to the code below, print values before checking them, before changing them, and that way the issue will surely be easy to fix.

```
public void Addcart(String category_name, long recipe_id, String recipe_title, String recipe_time, String recipe_image, String recipe_description, String video_url, String video_id, String content_type, String featured, String tags, long total_views, String _stringVal) {
try {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    // Check if order already exists
    String existingQty = CheckOrderExists(recipe_id);
    
    if (!existingQty.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
        // If order exists, update its quantity
        UpdateOrderData(recipe_id, _stringVal);
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Order updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("Addcart", "Order updated: Recipe ID: " + recipe_id + ", New Quantity: " + _stringVal);
    } else {
        // If order doesnt exist, insert a new row
enter code here

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_CAT_NAME, category_name);
        values.put(KEY_RECIPE_ID, recipe_id);
        values.put(KEY_RECIPE_TITLE, recipe_title);
        values.put(KEY_RECIPE_TIME, recipe_time);
        values.put(KEY_RECIPE_IMAGE, recipe_image);
        values.put(KEY_RECIPE_DESCRIPTION, recipe_description);
        values.put(KEY_VIDEO_URL, video_url);
        values.put(KEY_VIDEO_ID, video_id);
        values.put(KEY_CONTENT_TYPE, content_type);
        values.put(KEY_FEATURED, featured);
        values.put(KEY_TAGS, tags);
        values.put(KEY_TOTAL_VIEWS, total_views);
        values.put(KEY_QTY, _stringVal);
        
        // Insert the new row
        db.insert(TABLE_ADDCART, null, values);
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Order added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("Addcart", "New order added: Recipe ID: " + recipe_id + ", Quantity: " + _stringVal);
    }
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Handle exceptions
    Log.e("Addcart", "Error adding or updating order: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

}