# Android sqlite Value must be ≥ 0 but getColumnIndex can be -1 how to fix?

Tags: android, sqlite

_stringVal = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_QTY)); this cursor sqlite coming data error show how to fix error [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1RVy.png)

```
 public String CheckOrderExists(long recipe_id) {

    String _stringVal = "0";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ADDCART + " WHERE " + KEY_RECIPE_ID+ " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(recipe_id)});
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        _stringVal = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_QTY));
        if (_stringVal.equals("0")) {
            db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_ADDCART + " WHERE " + KEY_RECIPE_ID+" = ?" , new String[]{String.valueOf(recipe_id)});

        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return _stringVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you have the following line:

```
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_QTY));
```

Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor#getColumnIndex(java.lang.String)), the method getColumnIndex:

> Returns the zero-based index for the given column name, or -1 if the
> column doesn't exist. If you expect the column to exist use
> getColumnIndexOrThrow(java.lang.String) instead, which will make the
> error more clear.

To fix this, you have two options:

1. Check if the column index received by this method is -1
2. Use [getColumnIndexOrThrow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor#getColumnIndexOrThrow(java.lang.String)) but keep in mind that you will have to wrap it in a try/catch block as using this method might throw an IllegalArgumentException if the column doesn't exist

Comment: CODE NOT WORKING BRO PLZ HELP ME BRO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77593816/how-to-update-updateorderdata-sqlite-database-android

Comment: AddOrderData if condition not working else condition working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77593816/how-to-update-updateorderdata-sqlite-database-android

Comment: code new update plz show bro https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77593816/how-to-update-updateorderdata-sqlite-database-android

Comment: @jayraman - Those are completely different questions. If my answer helped you with the specific question you asked, please mark it as such so other people can find it more easily.

Comment: ok i will update bro

Comment: check bro https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77593816/how-to-update-product-quantity-updateorderdata-sqlite-database-android